# OpenCL C++ binding for clCreateFromGLTexture()

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to do OpenCL and OpenGL Interoperability as seen [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-and-opengl-interoperability-tutorial).

The function [clCreateFromGlTexture()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLTexture.html) is used but I'm using the C++ bindings for my project and can't find a equivalent function on their [documentation](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_memory.html).

Is there a binding for this or is there any way to convert a cl::Context object to a cl_context type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all `cl::` objects inherit `operator()` from `cl::detail::Wrapper< T >` which returns their cl_type. So it can be used like:

```
cl::context x; 
cl_context c = x();
```

Also, you might want to use `cl::ImageGL` that behaves like `cl::Image` and is created from OpenGL texture exactly via `clCreateFromGlTexture()` call.

Note that you still must use `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects` and `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects` even when using c++ classes.